# ctags doesn't parse some clib headers

Tags: vim, ctags

Okay, I've just installed ctags and I've tried to parse the whole C library with ctags like that:

```
ctags -I__wur --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS -f ~/.tags/tags /usr/include/*.h
```

It seems, that this line doesn't parse some of the libraries properly. For example if I hit C-] on fclose function, ctags directs me to /usr/include/stdio.h fclose's line and I can see all the info I need about the function. But strange stuff happens with function's prototypes, which are in string.h. For example, if I hit C-] on strcpy, I get the following message:

```
E426: tag not found: strcpy
```

So I decided to parse tags file like that:

```
ctags -R -I__wur --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS -f ~/.tags/tags /usr/include/
```

Now, if I hit g] on strcpy, I get to choose one of the following files to open:

```
/usr/include/bits/string.h
/usr/include/bits/string2.h
/usr/include/bits/string3.h
```

But somehow, I can't see /usr/include/string.h. What's the problem here? Am I using ctags incorrectly, somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that `/usr/include/string.h` is actually a symbolic link to `/usr/include/bits/stringx.h`. ctags is working properly.